# Wordpress@Digitalocean: Without any changes from my side, my website shows 'Welcome to Nginx'

Tags: wordpress, nginx, digital-ocean

There have been no changes on my Wordpress website, which I am hosting at Digitalocean on a one-click Wordpress install. For some reason it now displays the 'Welcome to Nginx' text. From my research so far I tried:
- to stop/restart nginx: on stop, the site is down, restart doesnt still displays the welcome text
- check if /etc/nginx/sites-available/default has root /var/www/html; under server
- check if nginx is runnig (it does)
- check if apache is running (it seems not to)
- check if its a problem of my device: no, I checked on my laptop, phone and tablet - the problem is the same

Any ideas on how to restore my website?

This is the output of nginx -T (the configuration file):

```
# Default server configuration
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php7.0-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}
```

and the output of tree /etc/nginx/ is:

```
/etc/nginx/
├── conf.d
├── fastcgi.conf
├── fastcgi_params
├── koi-utf
├── koi-win
├── mime.types
├── nginx.conf
├── proxy_params
├── scgi_params
├── sites-available
│   └── default
├── sites-enabled
│   └── default -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
├── snippets
│   ├── fastcgi-php.conf
│   └── snakeoil.conf
├── uwsgi_params
└── win-utf

4 directories, 14 files
```

Comment: Add the output of `nginx -T` to your question

Comment: @TarunLalwani done :)

Comment: Seems like your old wordpress config is no more there and that is why you are getting the issue. Post the output of `tree /etc/nginx/`

Comment: @TarunLalwani how does that happen?

Comment: check if `sites-available/default` has your old config? If not then your site config is no more there and you need to recreate it. Not sure what would have happened earlier